# Get USB printer information without CUPS

Tags: python, linux, printing, linux-kernel, usb

I would like to connect multiple printers via USB and send print-files to each of them.  I understand that printers are listed as `/dev/usb/lp0`, `/dev/usb/lp1`, where currently, I am using this python instruction to send a file to the printer

```
for files in os.listdir('/folder/with/print/files'):
        shutil.copyfile('/folder/with/print/files', '/dev/usb/lp0')
```

However, I have noticed that Linux does not label `lp0` and `lp1` in any particular order.  Since I am sending files to the printer like this, I do NOT want to use CUPS to get the information for each of my printers.  I would rather not make my print calls dependent on searching for a driver, since I will already have these files formatted for these printers. Instead, I want to find an alternative approach in attaining the printer information for lp* (lp0, lp1, etc).  I would preferably like to do this through python, or go through the Linux kernel with using `os` functions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing directly to the printer device try using lpr in a shell command!

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html

It looks like it lets you pick a printer by name.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get USB device Vendor/Model/Serial ID using `udevadm` command:

```
udevadm info -q property /dev/usb/lp0
```

Should be enough to distinguish between devices.